# What is the difference between ContactID and PersonAccountID

Tags: salesforce-id, person-accounts, accountcontactrelation

We have person Account enabled in our org and we would like to have Salesforce as the customer master DB. We thought of using one identifier across all the systems in our organisation. The previous CRM admin used and passed the contact ID field as the customer master ID to all integrated systems.

As we have Person Account enabled in our org I am sceptical and am thinking of using instead the Account ID?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

Person accounts are used in B2C scenario where you enable business to individual clients. Some examples could be shopping e commerce site, citizen self service portal. When you create person accounts it creates one contact and account.

For you the account is equivalent to client for whom you are providing services. You can either use account id or an auto number field to act as unique client index record.